# SignalR jquery sessionstorage

Tags: jquery, signalr, sessionstorage

I have build a livechat with help from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

Now i have that problem that i cant use sessionStorage to save the username so the user dont have to type a username everytime he/she enter the chat site on the website.

It's my first time working with web application and sessionStorage.

Hope someone can help me :)

Online view: http://chat.kibshede.dk/Chat.aspx

I have a class with this in it:
namespace SignalRChat
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
        }
    }
}

and a Owin class with:

namespace SignalRChat
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}

```js
<!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--Add script to update the page and send messages.-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
            chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
                // Html encode display name and message.
                var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
                var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
                // Add the message to the page.
                $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
                    + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
            };

            if (sessionStorage.getItem('UserName') != '#ContentPlaceHolder1_displayname') {
                // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
                var UserName = prompt('Enter your name:', '').toString();
                sessionStorage.setItem('UserName', UserName);
            }



            // Set initial focus to message input box.
            $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_message').focus();

            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub.
                    chat.server.send(sessionStorage.getItem('UserName'), $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_message').val());
                    // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                    $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel_ChatContainer" CssClass="container" runat="server">

        <asp:Panel ID="Panel_ChatContainer_Chat" runat="server">
            <asp:TextBox ID="message" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
            <asp:Label ID="displayname" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <ul id="discussion"></ul>
        </asp:Panel>

    </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Do your users have to log in to your site? If so you can use their existing session cookie.

Comment: I dont use login :/

Answer (score 1):

You need to change sessionStorage to localStorage to keep the username that the user sets. sessionStorage data only persists until the user closes the tab while localStorage will persist.

Comment: but cant i use sessionstorage to save the user name? 
I use session in the login anyways

Comment: You can save what they enter in whatever object you are using to log the session id for your user but if you want it so they don't have to enter the username every time they navigate to your site you need something that persists on the users end. You should put a break point in your code on your override of OnConnect / OnDisconnect and see how often they get called if you are navigating around your app.

Comment: i have ben trying to save the username in sessionstorage and made a "if" but for some reason the session or somewhere else is not working


if (sessionStorage.getItem('UserName') != '#ContentPlaceHolder1_displayname') {
                var UserName = prompt('Enter your name:', '').toString();
                sessionStorage.setItem('UserName', UserName);
            }

Comment: Sorry I completely missed that somehow. I edited my answer.